# Jquery load url into the current window target element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am loading a external content from a url using `jquery` `.load()` function this is attached into a onclick event function, the parent document is a prompt window.

Here is my HTML code this located on a Open Browser window.

```
window.open("http://localhost/content1.php", "_blank", "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=400,height=400");
```

Inside the window a `href` with a onlick event.

```
 <a href="#" onclick="getFeature('3','book1');">FEATURE / OPTIONS</a>
```

My `javascript` function the #mainContentTab is located on the body of the opened window.

```
 function getFeature(id,mod) {

    var  url = encodeURI('content2.php?ID='+id+'&mod='+mod);

        ('#mainContentTab').load(url);

 }
```

My problem is when two window is open and i click the function the two window load the same content at the same time, so i am trying the `.find()` function to load the content on a focused window only.

My code attempting the `.find()` function but its not working.

```
  function getFeature(id,mod) {

    var  url = encodeURI('content2.php?ID='+id+'&mod='+mod);

               $(this).find('#mainContentTab').load(url);

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the `#mainContentTab` is not unique that's why when you click/execute the function it will change the content of all `#mainContentTab`
since you are passing the id inside the `getFeature(id,mod)` function why don't you append that id on the `#mainContentTab`?

Example

```
<div id="#mainContentTab-3"></div>
```

Then revising your function into.

```
  function getFeature(id,mod) {

    var  url = encodeURI('content2.php?ID='+id+'&mod='+mod);


               console.log($('#mainContentTab'+id).load(url));

 }
```

The +id appends the id into the target element making it unique.

Comment: @Sarotobi no problem.